# Using a CALayer in an NSStatusBarButton

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I'm interested in drawing custom content in a NSStatusBarButton similar to the built-in battery menu bar app:

[image]

I'd like to use a CALayer due to the flexibility of drawing custom content. I've managed to add a layer-backed NSView to the button using this code:

```
// StatusView

class StatusView: NSView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.wantsLayer = true
    }

    override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func updateLayer() {
        if let layer = self.layer {
            layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor

            // Code adding text layer...
        }
    }

}

// MenuController

class StatusMenuController: NSObject {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            layerView.frame = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: len / 2, height: button.bounds.height)
            button.addSubview(layerView)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I'm adding a CALayer to the button of the NSStatusBarButton, which looks fine normally, but seems to have an opaque background when you click the menu item:

[image]

I've set the background color of the CALayer to transparent and the `isOpaque` property of the layer's view is `false`. Is there a way to get the view to actually blend with the background, similar to the battery menu bar app?

Thanks!

Comment: Set your StatusView `wantsLayer` property to `true`. More info at https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483695-wantslayer

Comment: It appears that it's already set to true.